# Need the count of every tagged product in magento

Tags: php, magento, tags, magento-1.7

I need to get the count of tagged product. I am getting the name and url. I am using this code:

```
<?php if( sizeof($this->getTags()) > 0 ): ?>
    <ul class="tags-list" style="margin-left:10px;">
        <?php foreach ($this->getTags() as $_tag): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $_tag->getTaggedProductsUrl() ?>" style="font-size:<?php echo $_tag->getRatio()*70+100 ?>%; text-decoration:none; font-family:Trebuchet MS;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_tag->getName()) ?></a>**(want the count here like 5)**</li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no tags available.') ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question; otherwise, I think it will be closed.

Comment: @ It's Your Fault: I need to show the count of every tags like
cloth(12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show the count of each tag, provided you have a method like `getTagCount()`, which will display the count of a given tag.

***Function can be defined as:*

```
//only an idea
<?php
public function getTagCount() {
    return count( $this->tag );
}
?>

<?php if( sizeof($this->getTags()) > 0 ): ?>
    <ul class="tags-list" style="margin-left:10px;">
        <?php foreach ($this->getTags() as $key => $_tag): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $_tag->getTaggedProductsUrl() ?>" style="font-size:<?php echo $_tag->getRatio()*70+100 ?>%; text-decoration:none; font-family:Trebuchet MS;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_tag->getName()) ?></a><?php echo $_tag->getTagCount();?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no tags available.') ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It give one after each tags. Means every time it takes $key=0 and hence $key+1=1

Comment: @mukund002 If you want a tag count, please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks the idea is really very easy and helpful but for some reason. It breaks the designs and not showing result.

Comment: @mukund002 - how does it break your design? Pleae give some detail. would help in debugging.